# Click all buttons via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('minds-subscribe-button'); 

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) 
{ 
    inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

That code works to click both buttons - `<button class="minds-subscribe-button">` and `<button class="minds-subscribe-button subscribed">`

I **don't** want to click the buttons that have `"minds-subscribe-button subscribed"`, **only** `"minds-subscribe-button"`.

Comment: `var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('minds-subscribe-button'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your for loop, you could execute:

```
if(!$(inputs[i]).hasClass("subscribed")){
   inputs[i].click();
}
```

It will verify if the input hasn't the class subscribed. If it's true, then click.

Comment: SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: This answer requires jquery, add this at the top of the page: `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: I am running this on a 3rd party website w/ Firefox console. jQuery 2.1.4 is already running on page.

Comment: @Andrew Ribeiro, I am running your code standalone. How would it look inside my for loop?

Comment: Does this look better? `var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('minds-subscribe-button'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {if(!$(inputs[i]).hasClass("subscribed")){
   inputs[i].click();
}}`

Comment: Dear @ArturasRosenbacher, I've tested what I answered and everything works perfectly. Could you look at http://codepen.io/andtankian/pen/EyWPNZ to see the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('minds-subscribe-button'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {if(!$(inputs[i]).hasClass("subscribed")){
   inputs[i].click();
}}
```